# Не вполне стандартный импорт данных из dbf файла

Tags: sql, oracle

Какими средствами можно провести импорт данных из dbf файла с дополнением стандартными значениями? Предположим, есть файл с двумя колонками:

```
| A | B |
|---|---|
| 4 | G |
| 7 | R |
| 2 | N |
| 8 | F |
```

Что, если я хочу загрузить его в таблицу, где в четвертой колонке вписывать одно и то же значение, а в пятой - номер строки? Теоретически, это можно было бы сделать триггером с секвенцией и стандартным значением для пятого столбца в таблице. Но я хочу чтобы номер строки начинался с 1 (а еще лучше с числа, которое я выберу) при каждой загрузке и чтобы можно было выбрать стандартное значение в пятую строку при каждой загрузке (Например 'Загрузка от 2020.01.31'). Другими словами, как загрузить этот .dbf-файл, чтобы в итоге получить:

```
| A | B | third |  D  |  E  |
|---|---|-------|-----|-----|
| 4 | G |  NULL | 'Hi'|  1  |
| 7 | R |  NULL | 'Hi'|  2  |
| 2 | N |  NULL | 'Hi'|  3  |
| 8 | F |  NULL | 'Hi'|  4  |
```

Я попробовал с помощью утилиты в dbForge, но он льёт в первозданном виде, не позволяя дополнить какой-то столбец постоянным значением или номером строки.

Comment: Импортируй во временную таблицу, а потом перегоняй в постоянную, с  любыми добавлениями и поправками.

Comment: @Akina - это то да, так или иначе задачу решить можно. Интересует именно возможность решить через готовый инструмент. Если есть импорт as-is, то хотя бы заполнение таблицы собственным стандартным значением ведь напрашивается. dbForge даже отображает системное стандартное значение  столбцов.

Comment: Абсурд. Мне нужны одни данные, другому - другие. Для того же dbForge было бы достаточно, чтобы одна колонка на одном шаге имела возможность к правке. Не пришло в голову тебе, а рассуждаешь о всех.

Comment: А в котором месте я сержусь? Человек не знает такого инструмента, ну так и бог с ним. Обычно, конечно, на вопросы реагируют те, кто что-то знает, а кто не знает - мимо проходит, но ведь это и не ответ, а коммент. Страна свободная, так сказать.

Comment: Ок. Но лично я такого инструмента не видел - ни для одной СУБД.

Comment: А я уже нашел подозрительный ролик на ютубе, где через TOAD грузят данные и в качестве источника можно указать не просто имя столбца (A или B), но и подозрительная опция Expression. Разбираюсь и тем временем поставил на закачку trial-версию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для поставленной цели, например, подходит среда TOAD от Dell. Для того чтобы импортировать данные, выполните:

1. Подключитесь к БД
2. Выберите в главном меню Database->Import->Import Table Data
3. В открывшемся мастере импорта выберите тип файла, укажите сам файл и т.д.
4. Когда дойдете до страницы с маппингом колонок источника и цели, на нужный столбец выберите в выпадающем списке вместо одного из столбцов источника строку Expression.
5. В открывшемся окне выберите нужное выражение. Для константы просто вбейте её в верхнее поле. Для счётчика можно использовать одну из предложенных переменных (например, TotalRowsAdded).
6. Выполните импорт

Comment: Решил все-таки оставить ответ, возможно кому-то будет полезным, раз даже члены сообщества со стажем не всегда слышали о подобных инструментах.

Comment: Всё бы хорошо в этом решении, но не нашел где можно было бы поменять кодировку. А так - импортит крякозябры. dbForge умеет менять кодировку, но там нет expression (или я не нашел)